# Iterating over lists using multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading, listiterator

Following code(part shown) creates objects of class DescCalculator and calculate descriptors and returns them as string arrays. A molecule and a ArrayList of Descriptor objects are passed in.

```
    private void calcDesc()
    {
        try
        {
        StatusPanel.setStatus("Calculating Molecular Descriptors Using CDK...\n");
        File df = new File(Settings.getCurrentDirectory() + sep + "molDesc.csv");
        FileWriter dfw = new FileWriter(df);
        LoadSDF lsdf1 = new LoadSDF(Settings.getCurrentDirectory() + sep + "marvin3D.sdf");
        List<IAtomContainer> mols3D = lsdf1.getCompounds();
        DescriptorEngine engine = new DescriptorEngine(DescriptorEngine.MOLECULAR);
        List<String> classNames = engine.getDescriptorClassNames();
        List<String> removeList = new ArrayList();
        removeList.add("org.openscience.cdk.qsar.descriptors.molecular.IPMolecularLearningDescriptor");
        classNames.removeAll(removeList);
        List<IDescriptor> instances = engine.instantiateDescriptors(classNames);
        engine.setDescriptorInstances(instances);

        List<String> headerItems = new ArrayList<String>();
        headerItems.add("CID");
        headerItems.add("MobCSA");
        for (IDescriptor descriptor : instances) {
            String[] names = descriptor.getDescriptorNames();
            headerItems.addAll(Arrays.asList(names));
        }
        ArrayList<IMolecularDescriptor> descriptors = new ArrayList();

        for (Object object : instances)
        {
        IMolecularDescriptor descriptor = (IMolecularDescriptor) object;
        String[] comps = descriptor.getSpecification().getSpecificationReference().split("#");
        descriptors.add(descriptor);
        }
        String headerLine = "";
        for (String header : headerItems) {
            headerLine = headerLine + header + ",";
        }

        dfw.append(headerLine+"\n");
        ExecutorService eservice = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads);
        CompletionService <List<String>> cservice = new ExecutorCompletionService <List<String>> (eservice);
        int k=0;
        for (IAtomContainer mol : mols3D)
        {
            DescCalculator dc = new DescCalculator(mol,descriptors);
            cservice.submit(dc);
            k=k+1;

        }
        for (int j=1 ; j<=k; j++)
        {
            StatusPanel.setStatus("Calculating Descriptors for Molecule "+j+"/"+compounds.size()+" Using "+threads+" Processors\n");
            List<String> dataItems = cservice.take().get();
                for (int i = 0; i < dataItems.size(); i++) {
                if (dataItems.get(i).equals("NaN")) {
                    dataItems.set(i, "NA");
                }
            }

            try {
                String dataLine = "";
                for (String data : dataItems) {
                    dataLine = dataLine + data + ",";
                }
                dfw.append(dataLine+"\n");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.toString());
            }
        }
 dfw.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Inside the class there is a for loop that goes over the list of descriptors as follows (part shown). This code runs into concurrent modification exception. If I use threads=1 or descriptor iteration inside a synchronized{} block the code runs fine but i don't get the parallellization needed.How do I iterate over the list inside class DesCalculator ??

```
    public class DescCalculator implements Callable<List<String>>{

    private IAtomContainer mol = new Molecule();
    private ArrayList<IMolecularDescriptor> molDesc;

    DescCalculator(IAtomContainer mol_, ArrayList<IMolecularDescriptor> molDesc_)
    {
        this.mol = mol_;
        this.molDesc = molDesc_;
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> call() {
        List<String> dataItems = new ArrayList<String>();
        try
        {
            String title = (String) mol.getProperty("PUBCHEM_COMPOUND_CID");
            dataItems.add(title);
            //String csa = Double.toString(mobcalCSA.get(ind));
            String csa = "NA";
            dataItems.add(csa);
            int ndesc = 0;
            for (IMolecularDescriptor descriptor : molDesc) {
                descriptor.calculate(mol);
                DescriptorValue value = descriptor.calculate(mol);
                if (value.getException() != null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < value.getNames().length; i++) {
                        dataItems.add("NA");
                    }
                    continue;
                }

                IDescriptorResult result = value.getValue();
                if (result instanceof DoubleResult) {
                    dataItems.add(String.valueOf(((DoubleResult) result).doubleValue()));
                } else if (result instanceof IntegerResult) {
                    dataItems.add(String.valueOf(((IntegerResult) result).intValue()));
                } else if (result instanceof DoubleArrayResult) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < ((DoubleArrayResult) result).length(); i++) {
                        dataItems.add(String.valueOf(((DoubleArrayResult) result).get(i)));
                    }
                } else if (result instanceof IntegerArrayResult) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < ((IntegerArrayResult) result).length(); i++) {
                        dataItems.add(String.valueOf(((IntegerArrayResult) result).get(i)));
                    }
                }

                ndesc++;
            } 

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return dataItems;
    }

}
```

Print Stack Trace

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.checkForComodification(AbstractList.java:372)
    at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(AbstractList.java:343)
    at org.openscience.cdk.ChemObject.notifyChanged(ChemObject.java:187)
    at org.openscience.cdk.ChemObject.setFlag(ChemObject.java:375)
    at org.openscience.cdk.graph.PathTools.depthFirstTargetSearch(PathTools.java:168)
    at org.openscience.cdk.graph.PathTools.depthFirstTargetSearch(PathTools.java:177)
    at org.openscience.cdk.graph.PathTools.depthFirstTargetSearch(PathTools.java:177)
    at org.openscience.cdk.graph.SpanningTree.getRing(SpanningTree.java:185)
    at org.openscience.cdk.graph.SpanningTree.getCyclicFragmentsContainer(SpanningTree.java:221)
    at org.openscience.cdk.atomtype.CDKAtomTypeMatcher.getRing(CDKAtomTypeMatcher.java:912)
    at org.openscience.cdk.atomtype.CDKAtomTypeMatcher.perceiveNitrogens(CDKAtomTypeMatcher.java:730)
    at org.openscience.cdk.atomtype.CDKAtomTypeMatcher.findMatchingAtomType(CDKAtomTypeMatcher.java:117)
    at org.openscience.cdk.tools.manipulator.AtomContainerManipulator.percieveAtomTypesAndConfigureAtoms(AtomContainerManipulator.java:719)
    at org.openscience.cdk.smiles.smarts.SMARTSQueryTool.initializeMolecule(SMARTSQueryTool.java:435)
    at org.openscience.cdk.smiles.smarts.SMARTSQueryTool.matches(SMARTSQueryTool.java:214)
    at org.openscience.cdk.smiles.smarts.SMARTSQueryTool.matches(SMARTSQueryTool.java:189)
    at org.openscience.cdk.qsar.descriptors.molecular.AcidicGroupCountDescriptor.calculate(AcidicGroupCountDescriptor.java:135)
    at edu.uconn.pharmacy.molfind.DescCalculator.call(DescCalculator.java:48)
    at edu.uconn.pharmacy.molfind.DescCalculator.call(DescCalculator.java:25)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

Comment: Seems that the code is incomplete. Are you modifying the `molDesc` collection anywhere?

Comment: In what way are you changing molDesc inside call()?  Is it necessary for other threads to see these changes?  Simplest solution is just to make a copy of the list in the constructor.

Comment: @Tudor seems so. OP can use `CopyOnWriteArrayList` as container for `molDesc`. But to tell for sure, one needs to know how often `molDesc` is updated and if is it at all correct for `molDesc` to be updated while `DescCalculator#call()` is executing.

Comment: I do not modify molDesc anywhere. I also tried CopyOnWriteArrayList..

Comment: then you should be able to just do `this.molDesc = new ArrayList<Thingie>(molDesc_);` in your constructor.  The entirety of the code that throws the exception would be helpful in understanding what you're trying to actually do.

Comment: Entire code and print stack trace added

Comment: Looks like the problem is actually that the descriptor objects themselves aren't safe for concurrent use.  Perhaps you should make a new set of separate descriptor objects for each worker thread, instead of reusing them?

Comment: Thanks everybody..Affe: You are absolutely right..descriptor objects are not thread safe..Generating them inside the DescCalculator class fixed the problem..

Answer (score 2):

You should not get the exception unless you are actually *modifying* a `Collection` at the same time you are walking across it.  Often this can be done in 1 thread by doing a delete from a `Collection` you are iterating across -- in a `for` for example.

But in your case I guess you are removing from `molDesc` list somewhere although I can't see that in the code sample you provided.  If you need to remove entries from the list then you will have to use some other mechanism to do the deletes.  You cannot alter the same collection in multiple threads unless it is somehow `synchronized`.

Couple other ideas:

- Now sure if it needs to be the exact same list.  You could have each thread work with a copy of the list.

  ```
  DescCalculator dc =
     new DescCalculator(mol, new ArrayList<IMolecularDescriptor>(descriptors));
  ```
- You could just pass in a `Collections.synchronizedList` copy of `molDesc` although I'm not sure that's what you want.

  ```
  List<IMolecularDescriptor> syncedList =
      Collections.synchronizedList(descriptors);
  ...
  DescCalculator dc = new DescCalculator(mol, syncedList);
  ```
- Each thread could keep a list of items that need to be deleted.  At the end you could use the `Future` when the thread is reaped to get the deleted list of items and remove them from the list at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Your molDesc field is shared state between 2 or more threads that access the call() method.  As you stated, the only way to avoid the CMEs is to wrap the iteration in a synchronized() block (which will prevent you from parallelizing), or use a threadsafe structure like CopyOnWriteArrayList as Victor mentioned.

Comment: I tried CopyOnWriteArrayList..The molDesc ArrayList is never modified in anyway..

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the problem is with descriptor objects which are not thread safe. I thank Affe for pointing it out ! Generating them inside DescCalculator class fixed the problem. I thank everyone for their input !